# How to get the FileRef property of a document library file with CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, provider-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver

I'm implementing a RER (remote event receiver) in a provider-hosted app with CSOM, I need the FileRef property of the file which was just uploaded, so how can I get it?

any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var fileName = "Document.docx";

ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sitecollectionurl"); 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List spList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test"); 
clientContext.Load(spList); 
clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 

if (spList != null && spList.ItemCount > 0) 
{
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery(); 
    camlQuery.ViewXml = 
     @"<View>  
           <Query> 
              <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='File'>"+fileName+@"</Value></Eq></Where> 
           </Query> 
            <ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /></ViewFields> 
     </View>";  

    ListItemCollection listItems = spList.GetItems(camlQuery); 
    clientContext.Load(listItems); 
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    var listItem = listItems.FirstOrDefault();
    var value = Convert.ToString(listItem["FileRef"]);
}
```

Comment: it works just great! thanks, one more question, in case that I need antoher field like for example ContentType where can i see the references of the fields for put them in the caml query.

Comment: add it inside `ViewFields` tag.  example `<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /></ViewFields>`

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when i replaced Eq with Contains operator and type as Text

```
 @"<View>  
       <Query> 
          <Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>"+fileName+@"</Value></Contains></Where> 
       </Query> 
        <ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /></ViewFields> 
 </View>";
```